# Video conversion tool that I pass this particular command to and will convert the video

Tags: video

I dont know the first thing about video conversion.
I've been told that I need to convert a video using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -movflags faststart OUTPUT_FILE
```

what is the simplest possible software for windows that can do this?
are INPUT_FILE and OUTPUT_FILE variables?
if so, can it be the same file?
should it be surrounded with quotation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tool **is** [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). You are not going to find another tool that only passes all the command line params (it would be useless).

There are several GUI tools that use ffmpeg (for whatever reason) and that will output such a command line in the background, but to use them you would still have to know what all those parameters mean and then press the appropriate buttons in the GUI, so you're back at square one (having to learn the meaning of the parameters).

So look up the ffmpeg documentation and find out what that line is actually doing.
Yes INPUT_FILE and OUTPUT_FILE are the full file name specifications of your input and output file.

Note that you cannot ask questions here about ffmpeg; this site is only for software recommendations. You should ask those questions on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) or in the [ffmpeg forums](https://www.ffmpeg.org/contact.html#Forums)